# Cannot select database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to display a `SQL` database using `php`.

I get an error:

```
Cannot Select Database (running local on XAMPP).
```

In `XAMPP` I went into `xampp-security` and changed the password of the superuser to "thisthing"

I have a file named: `mydb.sql`

mydb.sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `dpuForm` ( 
`ID` INT  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`JN` TINYTEXT  NOT NULL ,
`PN` TINYTEXT  NOT NULL ,
`QTY` TINYTEXT  NOT NULL ,
`DESC` TINYTEXT  NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO 'dpuForm' ('JN',...........yadayadayada
```

And here's my php:

```php
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="thisthing";
$database="mydb";

mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM dpuForm";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$num = mysqli_numrows($result);

mysqli_close();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <th>Job Number</th>
<th>Part Number</th>
<th>QTY</th>
<th>Description</th>

<?php
      $i=0;
      while ($i < $num) {
  $f1=mysqli_result($result,$i,"JN");
  $f2=mysqli_result($result,$i,"PN");
  $f3=mysqli_result($result,$i,"QTY");
  $f4=mysqli_result($result,$i,"DESC");
    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $f1; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f2; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f3; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $f4; ?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php $i++;} ?>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `@mysqli_select_db` Don't suppress error warnings on your database connection. And change your `die()` statement to `die('Unable to connect to database. '. mysqli_connect_error());`

Comment: How do you suppose I change that?

Comment: Remove the "@" from in front of the `mysqli_select_db` call

Comment: From console, can you log in this way: mysql -u root -p thisthing ??

Comment: I get the error:  mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in line 13

Comment: Did i call out the database selection correctly? "mydb" or should it be "mydb.sql"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

This is because you are using the procedural style of mysqli and not the object oriented.

Refer: [mysql database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

Comment: This is true, however, you don't need to select the DB in the connection, you can still use :  `mysqli_select_db($link, 'databse_name');`. And you are correct about the Query, as well, you'll have to supply the DB link each time you try to execute a sql statement.

Comment: Now I get this error:  Unkown Database "mydb" But this time my headers show (not the data) only the headers.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: yeah, i agree with your point. I guess either ways both of them work and it's just a matter of the programmer's choice to select whichever method he/she finds convenient

Comment: @bagofmilk: I am assuming by headers you mean the database column headers without any data. Am i correct? . Also, your `mydb.sql` is your MYSQL script name. Is `mydb` your DB name as well?

Comment: @aaron, yes I think you are on to something. I just noticed that .sql files need to be imported into PhpMyAdmin as MySQL files. I'm in the process of trying to figure out how to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

In Procedural style , [mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) expects 2 parameters .

```
$link = mysqli_connect( $host, $username, $password );

mysqli_select_db( $link, $database );
```

But first to import your mydb.sql using phpMyAdmin :

- Go to Databases tab and create a new database
- Then go to Import tab and import the mydb.sql

If you have already created database using phpMyAdmin and then you find that the .sql file is bigger than allowed size according to your setttings , one way is to import from command line ( Windows command Prompt , etc. ) :

```
mysql -u mysql-user-name -p database_name < mydb.sql
```

or ( Change paths appropriately ) :

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql -u mysql-user-name -p database_name < C:\mydb.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try to connect  to mysql_connect

e.g.

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password") or die("! server");

$db = mysql_select_db("databasename",$con) or die("! db");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello if You are using `mysqli_connect` then you should use following

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","mydb");
```

OR

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
```

try this......